# Is it possible to send a message to facebook for a user at a later time?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Suppose that a user logged into facebook on my website. On my website they write that they want to send a message to facebook. Then after some time I will log in and click to submit the message for this user.

From what I read so far it seems that this will not be possible but I want to make sure. From what I understood, once the user logs in on my website I get an access token and only using this access token can I send a message to facebook for that user. But I would think that the access token doesn't last for a long time so it won't help saving it in a DB.

Question: is there a way to do the above mentioned functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it through Facebook maybe something like [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/389849807718635) or maybe look [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15798/delay-a-wall-post-on-facebook) (similar question, you might find useful answer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I meant a different kind of functionality. I"m going to edit my question.